# Automatically reconnect to ODBC sources?

Tags: mysql, asterisk, odbc, unixodbc

I am using Asterisk 1.8.10.1 and a MySQL database connected via ODBC to store CDRs. When my MySQL database isn't available when Asterisk starts or has an outage while Asterisk is running, I would expect Asterisk to retry to connect to the database, but this doesn't happen! Anyone knows where I can enable some kidn of automatic reconnect to databases in Asterisk?

My res_odbc.conf looks like this:

```
[asterisk]
enabled => yes
dsn => asterisk-connector
username => user
password => pass
pre-connect => yes
pooling => no
limit => 1
idlecheck => 1
negative_connection_cache => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usualy it do reconnect on next realtime request.

Try this set

```
idlecheck => 300; ( will check connection in pool every 5 minutes)
connect_timeout => 5; ( how long to wait on reconnect)
negative_connection_cache=>10 ;( how long wait before reconnect)
pre-connect = yes; will allow you check if connection ok by issue "realtime show odbc status"
```

Also i recomend set limit to more then 1.